# Getting HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available Tomcat JSF Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, jsf

I'm implementing small web service application. In my Client side I've implemented firstly one bean. It was working fine and communicating with xhtml page. Then I decided to make a bean another class. Everything was working perfectly. Then I decided to delete first bean since didn't use it anymore. Now nothing works and I always see this "HTTP Status 404 - /ExchangeRatesClient/exchangeRates/index.xhtml"

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ExchangeRates</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Axis Admin Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>`enter code here`
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ExchangeRatesClient</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExchangeRatesClient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Exchange Rates Client</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- PrimeFaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSF 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ant</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-storeconfig</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jaspic-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-es</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-fr</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-i18n-ja</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jni</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util-scan</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-saaj</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

bean:

```
package exchange.web.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import exchange.web.bean.Currency;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "exchangeService")
public class ExchangeRatesServiceProxy implements Serializable, ExchangeRatesService {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1357125747412062186L;
    private String _endpoint = null;
    private exchange.web.service.ExchangeRatesService exchangeRatesService = null;

    private float amount = (float) 0.0;

    private String from = Currency.KZT.name();
    private String to = Currency.USD.name();
    private float result = (float) 2.2;

    public ExchangeRatesServiceProxy() {
        _initExchangeRatesServiceProxy();
    }

    public ExchangeRatesServiceProxy(String endpoint) {
        _endpoint = endpoint;
        _initExchangeRatesServiceProxy();
    }

    private void _initExchangeRatesServiceProxy() {
        try {
            exchangeRatesService = (new exchange.web.service.ExchangeRatesServiceServiceLocator())
                    .getExchangeRatesService();
            if (exchangeRatesService != null) {
                if (_endpoint != null)
                    ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) exchangeRatesService)._setProperty("javax.xml.rpc.service.endpoint.address",
                            _endpoint);
                else
                    _endpoint = (String) ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) exchangeRatesService)
                            ._getProperty("javax.xml.rpc.service.endpoint.address");
            }

        } catch (javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException serviceException) {
        }
    }

    public String getEndpoint() {
        return _endpoint;
    }

    public void setEndpoint(String endpoint) {
        _endpoint = endpoint;
        if (exchangeRatesService != null)
            ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) exchangeRatesService)._setProperty("javax.xml.rpc.service.endpoint.address",
                    _endpoint);

    }

    public exchange.web.service.ExchangeRatesService getExchangeRatesService() {
        if (exchangeRatesService == null)
            _initExchangeRatesServiceProxy();
        return exchangeRatesService;
    }

    public void invokeExchange() {
        try {
            result = this.exchange(Currency.valueOf(from).ordinal(), Currency.valueOf(to).ordinal(), amount);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public float exchange(int from, int to, float amount) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        if (exchangeRatesService == null)
            _initExchangeRatesServiceProxy();
        return exchangeRatesService.exchange(from, to, amount);
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public float getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(float result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Currency[] getCurrencies() {
        return Currency.values();
    }

}
```

Have no idea why it worked before and now just completely broken :(

Comment: Have you also deleted `index.xhtml` page ? Or you just removed it from "welcome-list" entries ?

Comment: No, i didn't delete it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Was working around and it seems now it works, although still don't understand why it worked before and why after I deleted that class it stopped work.

Answer (score -1):

In pom.xml:

```
<finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>
```

in web.xml:

```
<display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>
```

and in my .settings org.eclipse.wst.commom.component :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="JavaServerFaces">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent" tag="defaultRootSource"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="/ExchangeRatesClient/build/classes"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="JavaServerFaces"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```

And now it works as before I deleted that class. The pages is reached by http://localhost:8080/JavaServerFaces/exchangeRates/index.xhtml address